# Self hosting the APIM Developer portal: Unable to publish locally using "npm run publish"

Tags: node.js, azure-api-management, apim

Cloned the repository and followed all the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/wiki/Self-hosting-the-portal) but i am unable to publish locally using "npm run publish" folder. The publish is working fine in others' machines but only i have the issue in my machine.

### Expected behavior:

Code should be published to "dist/website" folder

### Actual Behavior:

Getting below error on running "npm run publish" command.

## Error:

(node:12516) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
(node:12516) _UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ***TypeError: invalid options argument
at optsArg (C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:136663:11)**
at mkdirp (C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:136454:10)
at C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:183119:13
at new Promise ()
at FileSystemBlobStorage.uploadBlob (C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:183117:16)
at LocalStyleBuilder. (C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:37575:42)
at Generator.next ()
at C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:37560:71
at new Promise ()
at module.exports../node_modules/@paperbits/core/publishing/localStyleBuilder.ts._awaiter (C:\Users\MAGALI\repos\Dev portal new\api-management-developer-portal-master\dist\publisher\index.js:37556:12)
(node:12516) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 11)
(node:12516) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code*.

Comment: Can you run `npm install` successfully. I try to run this project, but failed.

Comment: Yes I could run npm install and install all the dependencies successfully. What's the error you are getting while doing npm install?

Comment: Mahesh, I think you need to check your blob storage connection string, and if the storage is accessible from your machine. Meanwhile, we'll see how to improve our error messages.